# Spark dataframe orderBy using a variable

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to do something like this, but it gives an error. What is the right way of doing so while still using a variable?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
....
val seq = Seq[Column](new Column("colX"), new Column("colY"), new Column("colZ"))
someDataFrame.orderBy(seq)
```

I know that one can also use something like `orderBy("colX", "colY", "colZ")`, but here I want to use a variable because my order sequence would change on different conditions.

I get an error like this.

```
error: overloaded method value orderBy with alternatives:
  (sortExprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (sortCol: String,sortCols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to (Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you should convert your Array or List to a sequence of values (an actual sequence not a `Seq`)

```
someDataFrame.orderBy(seq:_*)
```

**Quick test here:**

**INPUT**

```
df.show
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  c|  0|
|  b|  1|
|  a|  0|
+---+---+


val s = Seq(new Column("_1"), new Column("_2"))

df.orderBy(s:_*).show
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  a|  0|
|  b|  1|
|  c|  0|
+---+---+
```